# echo Dupplicated Values in Array By Sort(First name be duplicated)

Tags: php

we have Array with input
The first input is the number of names in the list
Other inputs names on list
((Input Sample :
5
John
Mike
Alisson
John
Mike
))
WE want to Show duplicated names on output
(output for sample :
John
Mike
)

i wrote this code for inputs and steps :
but i need help for duplicated value and echo them

```
<?php
$n = readline();
for($i = 0; $i < $n ; $i++) {
    $name = readline();
    $names[$name]  = (isset($names[$name]) ? $names[$name] + 1 : 1);
    

?>
```